# Do bees pollinate 1/3 of the world's food sources?

Tags: nutrition

I was eating some almonds when I saw the lid of the Blue Diamond Almonds : Smokehouse Flavored can say that bees pollinate 1/3 of the entire world's food sources.

Is this claim true at all?

Answer (score 3):

**Not likely**, as a third of our diet is dependent on insects and not specifically bees.

The 1/3 measure has been cited in a [variety of manners](http://www.honeybeesuite.com/bees-pollinate-one-third-of-what-do-we-really-know/) from "1/3 of volume" to "one of every three bites" to "a third of the plants that we consume for food". It looks like the original quote, from 1976, is from a fellow by the name of McGregor, who was talking about insect pollination in general, not about bees, as seen in this [article](http://www.nap.edu/read/11761/chapter/6#105):

> Although estimates of the proportion of the human diet that is attributable to animal pollination are occasionally attempted and frequently cited (for example, McGregor’s 1976 estimate that one-third of the human diet can be traced directly or indirectly to animal pollination), the proportion likely varies among countries and regions and depends on dietary preferences, seasonal availability, cultural practices, and economic status of consumers.

This is apparently sourced from "McGregor, S.E. 1976. Insect Pollination of Cultivated Crop Plants. USDA Handbook 496. Washington: U.S. Department of Agriculture, Agricultural Research" ([link](http://www.ars.usda.gov/SP2UserFiles/Place/20220500/OnlinePollinationHandbook.pdf)).

The relevant bit discusses a little of the breakdown between animal and plant sources:

> Worldwide, more than 3,000 plant species have been used as food, only 300 of which are now widely grown, and only 12 of which furnish nearly 90 percent of the world’s food. These 12 include the grains: rice, wheat, maize (corn), sorghums, millets, rye, and barley, and potatoes, sweet potatoes, cassavas or
>   maniocs, bananas, and coconuts (Thurston 1969).1 The grains are wind-pollinated or self-pollinated, coconuts are partially wind-pollinated and partially insect pollinated, and the others are propagated asexually or develop parthenocarpically. However, more than two-thirds of the world’s population is in Southeast Asia where the staple diet is rice. Superficially, it appears that insect-pollination has little effect on the world’s food supply – possibly no more than 1 percent.
>
> Within the United States, which accounts for only about 6 percent of the world’s population, about 286 million acres were cultivated in 1969. About 180 million acres were devoted to the wind pollinated or self- pollinated crops, primarily barley, corn, oats, rice, rye, sorghums and wheat, grass hay crops, sugar beets, sugar cane, potatoes, sweet potatoes, and tobacco. About 60 million acres were devoted to crops that may receive some benefit from insect pollination but are largely self-pollinating (beans, cotton, flax, peanuts, peas, and soybeans). About 40 million acres were devoted to hay crops produced from bee-pollinated seeds (alfalfa, clovers, lespedezas). About 6 million acres were devoted to producing fruits, vegetables, and nuts–most of which are dependent upon insect pollination. Table 1 lists the cultivated crop plants, discussed herein, that are dependent upon or benefited by insect pollination. These plants provide about 15 percent of our diet.
>
> The animal products we consume contribute about an equal amount to our diet. These include beef, pork, poultry, lamb, and dairy products–derived one way or another from insect-pollinated legumes such as alfalfa, clover, lespedeza, and trefoil.
>
> More than half of the world’s diet of fats and oils comes from oilseeds–coconuts, cotton, oil palm, olives, peanuts, rape, soybeans, and sunflower (Guidry 1964). Many of these plants are dependent upon or benefited by insect pollination. **When these sources, the animal and plant products, are considered, it appears that perhaps one-third of our total diet is dependent, directly or indirectly, upon insect-pollinated plants**.

[A more recent study](http://aob.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2009/04/01/aob.mcp076.abstract) by the United Nations Food and Agriculture Organization, "How much does agriculture depend on pollinators? Lessons from long-term trends in crop production" comes up with different results:

> .... A recent analysis[ii] of yearly crop data maintained by the United Nations Food and Agriculture Organization (FAO) from 1961 to 2006 reached some divergent conclusions and shed light on the interacting complexity of the question “How important is animal-vectored pollination?”
>
> The authors of the FAO analysis concluded that **the proportion of global food production attributable to animal pollination ranges from 5% in industrialized nations to 8% in the developing world**. These numbers are in stark contrast with McGregor and can be explained by the fact that his and other earlier estimates tended to minimize the degree to which crops vary in their dependence on animal pollinators. About 75% of the world’s crops benefit to some degree from animal pollination; only 10% of that 75% depend fully on animal pollination.

Comment: I've read this several times, but I remain confused. Doesn't the last line suggest the answer is Yes?

Comment: Only if you consider bees to be the only insects.

Comment: Sorry for the edit clashes.